# Every orthogonal projection is a Hermitian operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am having a hard time with this proof

> Prove that every orthogonal projection is a Hermitian operator.  That is, if $V$ is an inner product space with subspace $W,$ prove that $T(v) = \operatorname{proj}_w (v)$ is a Hermitian operator.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f_{1}=g_{1}+h_{1}$, $f_{2}=g_{2}+h_{2}$ for $g_{1},g_{2}\in W$ and $h_{1},h_{2}\in W^{\perp}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\left<Pf_{1},f_{2}\right>&=\left<g_{1},g_{2}+h_{2}\right>\\
&=\left<g_{1},g_{2}\right>\\
&=\left<g_{1}+h_{1},g_{2}\right>\\
&=\left<f_{1},Pf_{2}\right>.
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you assuming that $V = W \oplus W^\perp$? That isn't true if $W$ is (infinite dimensional and) not closed.

Comment: So by the phrase orthogonal projection that $P$ onto $W$, it is assumed by $W$ is closed, no?

Comment: I don't have much background in this area so I wasn't aware of that. Thank you! By the way, do you know whether there exist Hermitian projections to non closed subspaces?

Comment: @user284331 yeah I think I remember somewhere during lecture that my professor said if a vector space othogonally project onto another vector space,  the vector space being projected on is closed

Comment: Assume that $P\in B(H)$, then $P$ is orthogonal projection if and only if $P$ is idempotent and self-adjoint. To have some sort of orthogonal which is not onto a closed subspace, we need only to look up an idempotent which is not self-adjoint, the matrix by $E_{11}+E_{12}$ is one example.